# How do I disable the camera shutter sound when taking a photo with my iPhone 6S?

Tags: iphone, camera

Even after I disabled the **ringer** and **muted** the phone, the shutter sound can still be heard on my iPhone 6S. Why?

I tried to fix it in Settings, and followed the instruction, but the camera still makes shutter sound.

What can I do to turn the sound off?

Comment: In some countries (Japan and Korea, that I know of) the shutter sound is mandatory as a privacy issue, so that people will know a camera is being used. In those countries, the sound cannot be muted. Are you in one of those countries?